# tkinter filedialog askfilename when open zip archive in shellbox don't see folders inside

Tags: python, tkinter

I use tkinter filedialog in python something like this - filedialog.askopenfilename(), it work nice and all, but only when i choose just files in simple folders. But when i open into .zip file i can see inside just files in archive root, but not any folders inside. Hovewer if i manually print in navigation path adding \foldername i go into there and see files in that subfolder and can choose them(but not subfolders if any present here).

Is there a way in filedialog to get path to file in .zip in (.zip\subfolder\file) with dialogbox so user can choose it in there?

If i use filedialog.asksavefilename() its work cool. In this dialogbox subfolders in .zip is visible. But i need choose a file, not save new one.

Comment: So you're saying that the dialog opened by `filedialog.askopenfilename()` is allowing you to see inside a zip file, but only one level? On my machine, the dialog doesn't allow me  to browse inside the zip

Comment: Yes it's allow to see inside zip file, but folders inside not visible just files. To look into zip file you need right click menu on it and choose open with explorer.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create and open the dialog?

Comment: Better use `zipfile` module to process zip file.

Comment: I ofcourse already use zipfile for work with zip. But i need GUI for user to choose files in .zip. Code somethink like these  "def Choose(): logfile = filedialog.askopenfilename()".   And Choose() just called from Button.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10. The dialog can look inside ZIP files by doing *Right click* -> *Open* (not to be confused with the *Open* button, which has the same effect as *Right click* -> *Select*, i.e. returning the ZIP file as the result of `askopenfilename()`), so anyways with *Right click* -> *Open* I can see the files inside the ZIP file but not the folders. Any solutions?